# Activerecord: find nth row in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

```
{ topic: "Foo", opportunity: Opportunity.limit(15)[0] },
{ topic: "Foo", opportunity: Opportunity.limit(15)[2] },
{ topic: "Foo", opportunity: Opportunity.limit(15)[7] },
{ topic: "Foo", opportunity: Opportunity.limit(15)[9] },
{ topic: "Foo", opportunity: Opportunity.limit(15)[11]}
```

Instead of doing `Opportunity.limit(15)[n]`, does active record offer any convenience functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`offset`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset).

Also note that not passing an `order` to your query does not guarantee that the query will return the instances ordered by the primary key. So it is best to pass an explicit `order`.

`Opportunity.order(:id).limit(1).offset(2)`